# UITableViewCell checkmark toggle not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working with a `UITableViewCell`.

When I tap it, it does toggle the first time between:
`UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` & `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

When I tap it, I even get the NSLogs that show that the toggle should be working properly.

But visually, only the first time I tap the cell does it actually toggle. Any ideas why?

If I close and reopen the viewcontroller, the checkmark/absence of checkmark is displayed properly (I have these saved), and once again I can only toggle once.

Any help please?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
int i = indexPath.row;

cell.textLabel.text = [[savedData.packArray objectAtIndex:i] name];
if ([[[savedData packArray] objectAtIndex:i] owned])
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Owned";
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"$0.99";
}

if ([[savedData.packArray objectAtIndex:i] owned])
{
    if ([[savedData.packArray objectAtIndex:i] activated])
    {
        [[savedData.packArray objectAtIndex:i] setActivated:NO];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSLog(@"No checkmark");
        //[cell setSelected:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [[savedData.packArray objectAtIndex:i] setActivated:YES];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@"Yes checkmark");
        //[cell setSelected:YES];
    }
    [self saveData];
}
else
{
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unlock %@?", [[savedData.packArray objectAtIndex:i] name]];
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unlock for $0.99?" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Purchase", nil];
    [av show];
    //[cell setSelected:NO];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

[self saveData];
//[cell setSelected:NO];
//return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Hi, please show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you tap the table cell, not only the UI, but you will also need to update the value of `activated` in `savedData.packArray`.

Comment: I overlooked `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method being implemented, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Your code to get the cell in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is incorrect. You want this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Why do you set the cell's text when the cell is selected? This should be done in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method. You should only be toggling the checkmark in the `didSelectRow` method.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're genius! I was reusing old code that didn't apply in that method, my bad lol :) I was wondering why it toggled the first time, but never again. By the way, I was setting the text because it was old code that I pasted in from a different method. Got rid of it. Thanks for helping me clear this up :) I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Glad to help but why did you accept the other answer telling you to do what you are already doing?